# How to make add-in pinned to email items?

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Like on the image:

[image]

Can't find any info on msdn. Also found sample Outlook add-ins on github, but they don't have icons on email items. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've realized that these icons appear only when you install an add-in from the marketplace. I deploy my plugin from xml file. That's why I don't see my icon

Comment: Do you mean you want the add-in icon appearing next to the reply button? Addin from xml file should be available, they are under the '...' menu and you can further customize to have the addin shown next to the reply button.

Comment: You can go to Settings -> View all Outlook Settings -> Customize Actions -> Toolbar  to configure the add-ins that appear on the Message compose surface. Additional documentation is here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-actions-on-your-messages-in-outlook-com-c8110dcb-892e-4903-94b3-f6eb41ada2a3

Answer (score 1):

It definitely does not apply to *all* add-ins installed from the marketplace. I have Salesforce plugin from marketplace and it is not pinned.

The configuration of the area where add-ins are pinned (known as "SurfaceArea") is stored in your mailbox under 7ae974c5-1af7-4923-af3a-fb1fd14dcb7a\OutlookOptions\RawJSON as a JSON object. If you are in a controlled environment, you can add GUID of your add-in to "ReadSurfaceAddins" property. You can use ApplicationImpersonation to do this for other people's mailboxes in your organization.

There are some plugins that pin themselves on install (the two examples I know are both from Microsoft Corporation). I tried to grab the cached manifest of one of those addins, change its GUID (so it won't conflict with the existing app in the store) and sideload it both as a user and via centralized deployment -- no luck, the add-in doesn't pin automatically. So the whatever magic makes those addins pin, does not happen in the manifest, but rather in some app store settings <strike>that aren't available to third party developers like us.</strike> UPD: I stand corrected, this feature is available to third parties as well - I've seen a third party add-in (Hubspot) that pins itself - again, this is an app store addin, not sideloaded.

Comment: I understand that you have already mentioned, it not something done from changing manifest file.

Is there any other way to pin my addin next to reply button in outlook ?

Comment: 1) "If you are in a controlled environment, you can add GUID of your add-in to "ReadSurfaceAddins" property. You can use ApplicationImpersonation to do this for other people's mailboxes in your organization."

2) If you're not in a controlled environment (as in -- you're distributing your add-in to other organizations), your add-in needs to be in Office365 add-in store to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings -> View all Outlook Settings -> Customize Actions -> Toolbar to configure the add-ins that appear on the Message compose surface. Additional documentation is here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-actions-on-your-messages-in-outlook-com-c8110dcb-892e-4903-94b3-f6eb41ada2a3